# Соединение между Android устройствами используя Bluetooth LE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

хочу найти устройства которые поддерживают bluetooth le
использую официальный пример 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html
код рабочий, я нахожу телевизор, мышки, клавиатуру  но ни один телефон на котором установлен и включен bluetoot le не отображается.
Что я не понял в этой жизни?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию телефоны находятся в режиме *undiscoverable*, то есть необнаруживаемые. Надо включить режим видимости/обнаруживаемости телефонов через bluetooth и тогда вы все увидите.